# correct usage with phrases

Tags: phrases, british-english

Why doesn't just *a sense* work as the subject in the following sentence? Why does it need *in a sense*?

> **A sense** we were witnessing someone pushing boundaries and defying conventions.

You could have:

> **A sense** of fear washed over him.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have an example of a sentence that doesn't work?

Comment: I thought the first example was a noun phrase versus the second with the subject (a sense of fear)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say:

> ✔ A sense of fear washed over him.

This is because *a sense of fear* is a noun phrase. What washed over him? A sense of fear. In other words:

> [A sense of fear] **washed** *over him*.
>   [A wave] **crashed** *into him*.
>   [A bird] **landed** *on the ground*.

But your first sentence is also constructed in such a way that *a sense* is being used as a noun phrase—and that doesn't allow it to fit with how the sentence finishes.

> ✘ [A sense] *we were* **witnessing** *someone pushing boundaries*.
>   ✘ [An apple] *we were* **eating** *something out of the oven.*
>   ✘ [Some ideas] *we were* **thinking** *nobody should work today.*

The sentence can be rephrased in a couple of ways. Both are grammatical, although only the first actually makes sense:

> *We were* **witnessing** [someone] *pushing boundaries*.
>   [A sense] *we were* **witnessing** *was pushing boundaries*.

---

[***In a sense***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20a%20sense), on the other hand, is actually an idiom that means something beyond the joining of the three individual words:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **in a/one sense** idiom
>   : in one way : from one point of view
>   // *In one sense*, he was correct.

So, when you add *in* to the start of *a sense*, you are changing it from a noun phrase to a dependent clause that is acting as either an adjectival phrase or adverbial phrase—depending on its context. (In your sentence, it's an adverbial phrase that modifies *witnessing*.)

In short, the sentence you are questioning can be (correctly) seen as follows:

> ✔ [In a sense,] *we were* **witnessing** *someone pushing boundaries and defying conventions.*
>   ✔ [In one way,] *we were* **witnessing** *someone pushing boundaries and defying conventions.*
>   ✔ [From one point of view,] *we were* **witnessing** *someone pushing boundaries and defying conventions.*

Comment: The performance was good, and there was a sense we were experiencing something new, a sense we were witnessing someone pushing boundaries and defying conventions.  (So is it a comma splice when its given  context or a noun phrase still?)

Comment: @bluebell1 That particular sentence may or may not be a comma splice. It depends on if you interpret *a sense we were witnessing* as a third item in a list (in which case it is a comma splice) or as an appositive that modifies *a sense we were experiencing something new* (in which case it is not a comma splice). It's open to interpretation. My inclination is to treat it as an appositive because of the repetition of *a sense*. By the way that's something quite different than your original question.